try to Remove a Div inside another div in javascript
do list app but the problem is I added on click function when the delete button is built but on the function side nothing works most of the time I get e  is undefined i checked all other pages but none of them have worked so far


let input_text = document.getElementById("input_text");
let Addbutton = document.getElementById("Addbutton");
let workList = document.getElementById("workList");
let xicon = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark"></i>';
let checkicon = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>';
Addbutton.onclick = function () {
  if (input_text.value === "") {
    alert("Please type something");
  } else {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let newLabel = document.createElement("label");
    workList.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.classList.add("workDiv");
    newDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
    newLabel.innerText = input_text.value;
    let newDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.appendChild(newDiv2);
    newDiv2.classList.add("buttonDiv");
    let newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newDiv2.appendChild(newButton);
    newButton.innerHTML = xicon;
    newButton.setAttribute("onclick", "Delete(e)");
    let newButton2 = document.createElement("button");
    newDiv2.appendChild(newButton2);
    newButton2.innerHTML = checkicon;

    input_text.value = "";
  }
};
function Delete(e) {
  e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
}
<section
  id="workList"
  class="mt-4 pl-2 h-fit w-11/12 flex flex-col gap-2"
  >
  <div class="workDiv">
    <label>todlapp1</label>
    <div class="buttonDiv">
      <button onclick="Delete()">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <button>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



I treated online guides and YouTube but none of them have worked so far i want when I click on the Delete Button it removes the main div that holds the task

You do not have element with id Addbutton anywhere in your HTML. So js code throws an error.

You can do it like this:


let input_text = document.getElementById("input_text");
let Addbutton = document.getElementById("Addbutton");
let workList = document.getElementById("workList");
let xicon = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark"></i>';
let checkicon = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>';
Addbutton.onclick = function () {
  if (input_text.value === "") {
    alert("Please type something");
  } else {
    /*let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let newLabel = document.createElement("label");
    workList.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.classList.add("workDiv");
    newDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
    newLabel.innerText = input_text.value;
    let newDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.appendChild(newDiv2);
    newDiv2.classList.add("buttonDiv");
    let newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newDiv2.appendChild(newButton);
    newButton.innerHTML = xicon;
    newButton.setAttribute("onclick", "Delete(e)");
    let newButton2 = document.createElement("button");
    newDiv2.appendChild(newButton2);
    newButton2.innerHTML = checkicon;

    input_text.value = "";*/
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += `<section
        id="workList"
        class="mt-4 pl-2 h-fit w-11/12 flex flex-col gap-2"
      >
      <div class="workDiv"><label>${input_text.value}</label><div class="buttonDiv"><button onclick="Delete(this)"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark" aria-hidden="true">Delete</i></button><button><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check" aria-hidden="true">Info</i></button></div></div>
</section>
`;
  }
};
function Delete(context) {
  context.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(context.parentNode.parentNode);
}
<div id="container"></div>
<input id="input_text" type="text">
<button id="Addbutton">Add</button>



Notes:

I have made sure you have a proper Addbutton
I have changed the way it's generated to create proper sections. You might want to change the onclick of Addbutton to something else, but that's not very relevant to the question, the only reason I changed it is to be able to test the remove button
I have changed the delete function to work with the object we have

